# Multi Label Classification on Data Columns in Tables

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, classification, supervised-learning, multilabel-classification

I am seeking guidance on a machine learning problem involving the tagging of data columns. Currently, I have a system where users can add multiple tags to a columns in a table. However, I want to automate the tagging of new columns by using Multi Label Classification. I have extracted 21 features from each column by doing a column analysis on the column values. The features obtained would include statistical values such standard deviation, max,min, kurtosis and etc. Am I on the right path in using these features as inputs for a Multi Label Classification model ? Right now I am focusing on numeric values in columns.

Comment: You will get better response if you ask this question on [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up